# Ionic - animating ion-nav-view when using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is the a way to animate the views that taking place each time i am tapping on a ion-tab?

index.html

```
<ion-side-menus>

    <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="NavCtrl" drag-content="false">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view animate="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view> //// animate is not working!
    </ion-side-menu-content>

  ...
```

I am using the ui-router and i have a tabs.html which i use for my tabs stack,
each ion-tab has it's `<ion-nav-view name="...">`
and everything working just fine bu not the animation, it just won'lt work at all.

Comment: This link might be useful for you http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/animation-slide-left-right-not-all-pages/1630

Comment: My problem is not the ability to enable/disable side menu swiping but getting the ion-tabs to bring the view with animations and not just pop them, but thanks anyway.

Comment: By the ionic framework forum, this issue might be an unfixed bug in v1.1.0